# Facebook API to fetch conversation thread between two people

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was looking for an API to fetch a conversation thread between two people

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't exist.

You can not access user-to-user conversations any more, access to user messages has been removed a long time ago.

Only messages between a user and a page can be retrieved by API.

Comment: I think i could work with that too, i tried going through the docs but couldnt seem to get it together. If you could help out. Thank you in advance

Comment: Used to work via the /pageid/conversations edge, but the documentation for that appears to have gone; it might be that they want you to handle this kind of stuff via Messenger API these days.